# Добавление записей в JList из метода другого класса

Tags: java

Добрый день!
Помогите разобраться. Есть два класса: Tree и List. Необходимо, чтобы когда делаешь click по "листу" JTree этот самый "лист" в виде String уходил как новая запись в JList. Всё вроде как верно, ошибок нет, но ничего и не происходит.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode;
import javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel;

public class RunProg extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
        frame.add(new tree());
        frame.add(new list());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class tree extends JPanel {

    final   String     ROOT  = "Корневая запись";
    final   String[]   nodes = new String[]  {"Напитки", "Сладости"};
    final   String[][] leafs = new String[][]{{"Чай", "Кофе", "Коктейль", 
                                               "Сок", "Морс", "Минералка"},
                               {"Пирожное", "Мороженое", "Зефир", "Халва"}};
    private list list;

    tree(){
        list = new list();
        DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(ROOT);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode drink = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodes[0]);
        DefaultMutableTreeNode sweet = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(nodes[1]);
        root.add(drink);
        root.add(sweet);
        for ( int i = 0; i < leafs[0].length; i++)
            drink.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(leafs[0][i], false));
        for ( int i = 0; i < leafs[1].length; i++)
            sweet.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(leafs[1][i], false));
        DefaultTreeModel treeModel1 = new DefaultTreeModel(root, true);
        JTree tree1 = new JTree(treeModel1);
        tree1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                  DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) tree1.getLastSelectedPathComponent();
                  if (node == null) return;
                  String s = node.toString();
                    list.addlist(s);
             }      
        });   
        add(new JScrollPane(tree1));
        setSize(400, 300);
        setVisible(true);         
    }       
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class list extends JPanel {

    DefaultListModel<String> dlm = new DefaultListModel<String>();
    public JList<String> list;

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    list(){
        list = new JList(dlm);
        dlm.addElement("Чай");
        list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,200));
        list.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Список")); 
        add(new JScrollPane(list));
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void addlist(String str) {
        dlm.addElement(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Может нужно вызвать repaint() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашей программе создаются два разных объекта `list`.

Один отображается в окне:

```
frame.add(new list());
```

Второй создается в дереве:

```
tree(){
    list = new list();
```

Во второй список Вы добавляете элементы. Первый не изменяется совсем.

Чтобы исправить это Вам нужно либо передать дереву ссылку на список, либо создавать список в дереве и затем добавлять его в окно.

Например (первый способ):

```
//в методе main
list list = new list();
frame.add(new tree(list));
frame.add(list);

//в конструкторе tree
tree(list listToAdd){
    list = listToAdd;
```

P.S. В коде значительно легче искать ошибки если соблюдаются правила именования. Осмысленные названия классов и объектов (`FoodsMenuTree`, `OrdersList`, `selectedProducts`) упростят чтение кода на порядок.

Comment: Спасибо. Я дописал:

Comment: Спасибо, в классе list, я объявил dlm и list как static и заработало.

Comment: @Platon это не очень хорошо. Если `dlm` и `list` статичные, то теряется смысл класса `list` — разные объекты будут управлять одним и тем же.

Comment: @Platon Пожалуйста. Если ответ решает Вашу проблему, то [отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).